# How do I download Ubuntu 14.04.3? I'm using a hp Chromebook and it says that it doesn't support the file

Tags: steam, chromebook

Hi trying to get Linux on a hp Chromebook and learned that you need Ubuntu to do it. My goal is to get steam on it because I have two Chromebooks, one for work and want one for gaming, but every time I try to download the file it won't work.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: How, and from where, are you trying to download the file?

Answer (score 0):

OSU (Oregon State University?) has a public FTP server which hosts Ubuntu mirrors. The releases are at ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu-releases/
Your browser should be able to navigate to that address in order to download an ISO.